# Why does float64 produce a RuntimeWarning where float produces a nan?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, warnings, infinity

I'm using the `warnings` module to raise warnings as errors.

When I call my function `plot_fig_4`, I get the following error:

```
In [5]: plot_amit.plot_fig_4()
g: 1 of 3
theta_E: 1 of 1000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeWarning                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5a631d2493d7> in <module>()
----> 1 plot_amit.plot_fig_4()

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/plot_amit.pyc in plot_fig_4()
    130                                                                     tau_0, tau,
    131                                                                     theta_E_,
--> 132                                                                     H)
    133 
    134             # Iterate through theta_I, starting at the lowest value.

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/plot_support.py in _get_d_phi(mu, sigma, tau_0, tau_i, theta_i, H)
   2059     for (i, mu_), (j, sigma_) in itertools.product(enumerate(mu),
   2060                                                    enumerate(sigma)):
-> 2061         phi[i, j] = _get_phi(tau_0, tau_i, theta_i, mu_, sigma_, H)
   2062     import pdb
   2063     pdb.set_trace()

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/plot_support.py in _get_phi(tau_0, tau, theta_over_J, mu_over_J, sigma_over_J, H)
   1835 
   1836     # Compute the integral.
-> 1837     integral = _integrate_little_phi(lower, alpha)
   1838 
   1839     # Compute phi.

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/plot_support.py in _integrate_little_phi(lower, upper)
   1869     upper_int = _integrate(upper)
   1870     lower_int = _integrate(lower)
-> 1871     return upper_int - lower_int
   1872 
   1873 

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

OK.  So I stick a `pdb.set_trace` inside `_integrate_little_phi`, just before the line at which the error is raised, re-run, and inspect the values of the relevant variables:

```
In [7]: plot_amit.plot_fig_4()
g: 1 of 3
theta_E: 1 of 1000
> /home/dan/Science/dopa_net/plot_support.py(1873)_integrate_little_phi()
-> return upper_int - lower_int
(Pdb) upper_int
inf
(Pdb) lower_int
inf
(Pdb) type(upper_int)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
(Pdb) type(lower_int)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Huh.  So the error was raised because I was subtracting infinity from infinity.  Can I replicate that?

```
(Pdb) upper_int - lower_int
*** RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Yes.  But wait a minute.  Let's try one more thing:

```
(Pdb) np.inf
inf
(Pdb) type(np.inf)
<type 'float'>
(Pdb) np.inf - np.inf
nan
```

What the what?  When I directly subtract infinity from infinity using `np.inf` (where `np` is `numpy`), I get `nan`, not the `RuntimeWarning`.

Why do I get `nan` in this instance and `RuntimeWarning` in the other?  **I have posted the difference in type (`float` versus `float64`) deliberately.  The question is, why do these (trivially) different types produce different results?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the case of `np.inf` , the type is `float` (the basic datatype) , whereas in case of `upper_int` / `lower_int` the data type is `numpy.float64` . Similar issue can be reproduced by -

```
In [7]: a = np.float64('inf')

In [8]: type(a)
Out[8]: numpy.float64

In [9]: a - a
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[9]: nan
```

For the case of `np.inf` / `float` -

```
In [3]: float('inf') - float('inf')
Out[3]: nan

In [11]: np.inf
Out[11]: inf

In [12]: type(np.inf)
Out[12]: float
```

---

I think this may be because in case of normal `inf` , you cannot get it from calculation. Example -

```
>>> 123123123123. ** 2
1.5159303447561418e+22
>>> _ ** 2
2.298044810152475e+44
>>> _ ** 2
5.281009949468725e+88
>>> _ ** 2
2.788906608638767e+177
>>> _ ** 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Instead you always get an overflow error.

Whereas when using `np.float64` , you can get the infinity value from calculation (though even that time it would throw a warning) -

```
In [63]: n = np.float64('123123123123123123123')

In [64]: n
Out[64]: 1.2312312312312313e+20

In [65]: n = n ** 2

In [66]: n = n ** 2

In [67]: n = n ** 2

In [68]: n = n ** 2
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':

In [69]: n
Out[69]: inf
```

Hence, since you can get `np.float64` infinity through calculation, they are throwing more warnings, when you try to do more calculations on it that may try to reduce the number from infinity to a much smaller value , that is subtracting/dividing by infinity (multiplication or addition of infinity is fine, since adding infinity to infinity would only give back infinity). Example -

```
In [71]: n - n
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[71]: nan

In [72]: n/n
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[72]: nan

In [73]: n*n
Out[73]: inf
```

Though in your case , I believe you may have gotten a direct infinite value from source.

Comment: right.  it didn't elude me that the types were different.  i inspected the types deliberately, and posted them because they were different.  the question is, why is the result different when the types are (trivially) different?

Comment: ah, nice update.  it may be noteworthy that i'm getting the `float64` within my function as the output from a `scipy.special` function.  perhaps the `scipy` developers were aware of this difference when they decided to use `float64` as opposed to `float` in their functions.

Comment: also, there are all kinds of situations in which you get a warning with `np.float64('inf')` and not `np.inf`: e.g., `0 * x`, where `x` is one or the other.

Comment: Yes, anything that would result in a nan.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any reason a subtraction of two `float64`s should raise a warning where a subtraction of two `float`s doesn't.

**Hence, this appears to be a bug in `numpy`.**

My recommendation (to myself) is to convert the `float64`s to `float`s at the time of the subtraction: i.e.,

```
return upper_int - lower_int
```

becomes

```
return float(upper_int) - float(lower_int).
```

This prevents the warning.

(Of course, there may be situations in which a warning for this subtraction is desired -- for these, I'd give the opposite recommendation -- i.e., keep things as is.  In a sense, it's nice to have this toggle for the warning.)