# How to convert a numpy array from 'float64' to 'float'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, casting

How do I convert a `numpy` `array` from type `'float64'` to type `'float'`?  Specifically, how do I convert ***an entire `array`*** with `dtype` `'float64'` to have `dtype` `'float'`?  Is this possible?  **The answer for *scalars* in the thought-to-be duplicate question above does not address my question.**

Consider this:

```
>>> type(my_array[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>

>>> # Let me try to convert this to 'float':
>>> new_array = my_array.astype(float)
>>> type(new_array[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>

>>> # No luck.  What about this:
>>> new_array = my_array.astype('float')
>>> type(new_array[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>

>>> # OK, last try:
>>> type(np.inf)
<type 'float'>
>>> # Yeah, that's what I want.
>>> new_array = my_array.astype(type(np.inf))
>>> type(new_array[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

If you're unsure why I might want to do this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32429925/2623899) and its answers.

Comment: AFAIK `float` and `float64` are equivalent in numpy.

Comment: @farenorth i'm guessing you didn't click to the linked question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types)

Comment: maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types

Comment: @tzaman i think there's a subtle difference between the two questions.  the answers there, for example, provide ways to convert individual scalars from `numpy` types to native python types.  i want to convert the `dtype` of the `array` itself.  but maybe this is impossible . . .

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You're not looking for `float32` are you?

Comment: @farenorth naa, that doesn't work for my purposes.  the issue is that `inf - inf` raises a `RuntimeWarning` iff the `inf`s are of type `float32` or `float64` -- but not if they're of type `float`.  i'm trying to avoid the warning.  but i think `numpy` forces its `array`s to use its float types, specifically so that its warnings work.

Comment: You can ignore errors or catch them using either warnings or np.errstate.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh yeah, i've been doing that.  i don't want to ignore them, generally, and i thought switching types might obviate having to catch them.

Comment: Well you can ignore specific warnings with np.errstate so you don't have to hide other warnings.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh ah, OK, yeah, that's cool.  thanks.  i'd been catching the warnings with the `warnings` module and `try`/`except` blocks, but `errstate` does seem much better.

Comment: @dbliss, you can also try setting the dtype to be "object", since it then stores the data using Python types, as shown here, which solves the np.inf - np.inf error:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh ah, that's a great option, too.  but i think the best, clearest thing for me to do in my code is to carry out that subtraction in an `np.errstate` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous type `float` like this

```
>>> new_array = my_array.astype(type('float', (float,), {}))
>>> type(new_array[0])
<type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, actually when you use Python's native `float` to specify the dtype for an array , numpy converts it to `float64`. As given in [documentation -](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)

> Note that, above, we use the Python float object as a dtype. **NumPy knows that `int` refers to `np.int_`, `bool` means `np.bool_` , that `float` is `np.float_` and `complex` is `np.complex_`**. The other data-types do not have Python equivalents.

And -

> *float_*   -  Shorthand for float64.

This is why even though you use `float` to convert the whole array to float , it still uses `np.float64`.

According to the requirement from the other question , the best solution would be converting to normal float object after taking each scalar value as -

```
float(new_array[0])
```

---

A solution that I could think of is to create a subclass for `float` and use that for casting (though to me it looks bad). But I would prefer the previous solution over this if possible. Example -

```
In [20]: import numpy as np

In [21]: na = np.array([1., 2., 3.])

In [22]: na = np.array([1., 2., 3., np.inf, np.inf])

In [23]: type(na[-1])
Out[23]: numpy.float64

In [24]: na[-1] - na[-2]
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[24]: nan

In [25]: class x(float):
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [26]: na_new = na.astype(x)


In [28]: type(na_new[-1])
Out[28]: float                           #No idea why its showing float, I would have thought it would show '__main__.x' .

In [29]: na_new[-1] - na_new[-2]
Out[29]: nan

In [30]: na_new
Out[30]: array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, inf, inf], dtype=object)
```

Comment: clever answer, thanks.  that said, i think the best answer -- at least for my purposes -- is to ignore the specific warning i'm getting with `float64`s using `np.errstate` -- see the comments above.

Comment: I can answer a few of those. Numpy stores everything that it cannot find a suitable dtype for as "object", which is a Python object. In the case of your class X, it cannot see the float through class inheritance, so it chooses object. Since the type of the values in na_new are all floats, but the dtype is object, it means that everything is stored using a Pythonic type rather than the numpy float64.

You can, however, perform math on object dtypes, which does provide some advantages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea if you're trying to stay in numpy, but if you're done calculating and are moving out into native python, you can use

```
ndarray.tolist()
```

This converts arrays to lists (of lists) of appropriate native types. It also works on numpy scalar values.